# Pinescript - How to Alert() just once the first time condition triggered

Tags: pine-script

Tradingview Pinesctipt V5

I create the alert() in my strategy. I want my alert to just alert once the first time condition is meet but in continue alert every time the condition is meet. How can I fix this.

```
if ta.cross(close,triggerprice)
    alert("Price Trigger", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var isTriggered = false 
if ta.cross(close,triggerprice) and not isTriggered
    alert("Price Trigger", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    isTriggered := true
```

Comment: I've coded this but it returns no alert at all even the condition is meet. Is there something I can do ? Big big thanks

Comment: This will not work because pinescript is a vector based streaming environment. Meaning the script is evaluated on every tick, isTrigger will be reset the original value. Having a stateful script will likely lead to other bugs.

Comment: @DanielRam  `isTrigger` will not reset the original value, if you're using `var` or `varip` type modifiers.